# Python Tkinter : Area of Scrollbar Frame Window Expand Vertically when main window is resized

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

I am using this code to develop my project taken from this websites only. But i am not able to make frame window extend vertically when main window is resized. i have tried my options but no luck. The frame window size is fixed. i want it to change dynamically when main window is resized. thanks in advance.

```
from Tkinter import *

def data():
    for i in range(50):
       Label(frame,text=i).grid(row=i,column=0)
       Label(frame,text="my text"+str(i)).grid(row=i,column=1)
       Label(frame,text="..........").grid(row=i,column=2)

def myfunction(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=200,height=200)

root=Tk()
sizex = 800
sizey = 600
posx  = 100
posy  = 100
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

myframe=Frame(root,relief=GROOVE,width=50,height=100,bd=1)
myframe.place(x=10,y=10)

canvas=Canvas(myframe)
frame=Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(myframe,orient="vertical",command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=frame,anchor='nw')
frame.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)
data()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely what you mean by "frame window" -- those terms are mutually exclusive. A frame is a widget that is in a window.  I'm going to assume you want the frame full of widgets to expand.

You have a couple of problems working against you. The first is that you're putting the canvas in a frame, but you haven't configured the frame to expand. If the frame doesn't expand, the canvas can't either.

You're using `place`, but that's a poor choice IMO, especially when the frame is the only widget in root. A better choice is `pack`. Since you're placing it at 10,10, I assume that means you want a 10 pixel margin around the edges.

```
myframe.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
```

If you want to use `place` instead, the options are a bit more complicated. You can use a relative width and  height to have it stay in sync with the main window. If you combine a relative width and a fixed width, they are additive. Thus, a relative width of 1.0 (100%) and a width of -20 means it is the full width of the window minus 20  pixels. (10 pixels on each side, since you're placing it at 10,10)

```
myframe.place(x=10,y=10, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0, width=-20, height=-20)
```

Once you do that, it exposes the next problem: the canvas doesn't expand to fit the frame. You're using `pack` which is a good choice, but you're failing to tell the canvas to fill the space given to it.

Change the code to add it to the frame like this:

```
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bryan Oakley. Nice Explanation. "frame window" means the area which contains all label widgets. It's height is fixed (height=200) in line 10.     canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=200,height=200)
 . This height should extent up to bottom when main window is resized.

Comment: @MritunjayKumarjaykr: just to be clear, even though you set the height to 200, it's not fixed. Because of the pack or place options, the size will change.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bryan Oakley. I did it. now it's working fine. your explanation is very very good. it helped me a lot to clear my doubt. i really appreciate you and the way of your explanation from the bottom of my Heart !! Thank you so much once again.